# Trying to access children nodes in docx file

Tags: java, xml, docx

I need assistance using the dom4j parser with accessing child nodes in a docx XML file.

I have created a node list using:

```
 List<Node> nodes = document.selectNodes("/w:document/w:body/w:tbl/w:tr/w:tc");
```

But, Im dont know how to find the child nodes of that selectNode group.
The docx file is a table listing that Im editing and attempting to update our DB.

I need to stay at this level because I need to know which column the data is in.
I need to get to the Quantity

I'd like to getchild at the  level. I need to determine if any data is missing in any column.

Thank You for your help
<

```
w:tc>
    <w:tcPr>
        <w:shd w:val="clear" w:color="auto" w:fill="FFFFFF"/>
        <w:tcBorders>
            <w:left w:val="single" w:sz="4"/>
            <w:top w:val="single" w:sz="4"/>
        </w:tcBorders>
        <w:vAlign w:val="top"/>
    </w:tcPr>
    <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="Style2"/>
            <w:framePr w:w="10805" w:wrap="notBeside" w:vAnchor="text" w:hAnchor="text" w:xAlign="center" w:y="1"/>
            <w:widowControl w:val="0"/>
            <w:keepNext w:val="0"/>
            <w:keepLines w:val="0"/>
            <w:shd w:val="clear" w:color="auto" w:fill="auto"/>
            <w:bidi w:val="0"/>
            <w:jc w:val="left"/>
            <w:spacing w:before="0" w:after="0" w:line="190" w:lineRule="exact"/>
            <w:ind w:left="200" w:right="0" w:firstLine="0"/>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rStyle w:val="CharStyle15"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>Quantity</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
</w:tc>
```

Comment: Could you give a snippet of the XML you are parsing? What child nodes you must to select?

Answer (score 0):

To find the child nodes of current context node, you have to specify [RelativeLocationPath](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-RelativeLocationPath) which is not start by `'/'` char.

```
for (Iterator iterator = nodes.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    Node node = (Node) iterator.next();
    node.selectNodes("w:tcPr");//="child::w:tcPr", child is the default axis of location path
    //The API return child nodes `w:tcPr`
}
```

> node.selectNodes("w:tcPr/w:shd");

The API return 1 node [/w:document/w:body/w:tbl/w:tr/w:tc/`w:tcPr/w:shd`];

> node.selectNodes("*/w:shd"); //select grand children "w:shd" of context node

The API return 1 node [`w:tcPr/w:shd`]; If node `w:p/w:shd` exist, it will be selected.

> node.selectNodes("self::node()//w:shd"); //XPath="self::node()/descendant-or-self::node()/w:shd"

The API return 2 nodes [`w:tcPr/w:shd`,`w:p/w:pPr/w:shd`]; If node `w:shd` exist, it will be selected.

> node.selectNodes("*//w:shd");//XPath="child::node()/descendant-or-self::node()/w:shd"

The API also return 2 nodes [`w:tcPr/w:shd`,`w:p/w:pPr/w:shd`]; But if node `w:shd` exist, it will **NOT** be selected.

Comment: How do I select the select the answer?

Comment: What do you mean? If you want to get text node `"Quantity"`, you can call `node.selectSingleNode("w:p/w:r/w:t").getText()`.